# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer

У меня ошибка "Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".
Но у меня версия PHP 8.1.17.
Можете подсказать причину.

Comment: что говорит консоль на команду `php -v`?

Comment: PHP 8.1.17 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2023 14:38:17) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.17, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: Странно. У меня пишет версия PHP 8.1.17, но пишет такую ошибку (

Comment: Создайте файл напр. info.php с содержимым `phpinfo();` откройте его в браузере и смотрите какая версия там

Comment: PHP Version 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18

Comment: Это правильный заголовок в phpinfo ?

Comment: Если у меня php 8

Comment: В настройках сервера обновите версию (скорее всего что-то типа `sudo a2dismod php7.4`  и `sudo a2enmod php8.1` для apache2 + restart)